# Corrugated steel sheet

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

> **Text only:**
>
> A $2.2 \text{ m}$ wide rectangular steel plate is corrugated as shown in the diagram. Each corrugation is a semi-circle in cross section having a diameter of $\text{7 cm}$. What will be the width of the steel sheet after it is corrugated?

In the problem given below how to tackle the one with area of the second diagram. Help me to do this.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** One corrugation that takes the form of a semi-circle which has a diameter of $7 \text{ cm}$ as given by the problem. This means the arc length of one corrugation is half of the circumference, which is $\frac 12(2\pi (\frac{7 \text{ cm}}2))\approx 11.0 \text{ cm}=0.11\text{ m}$.

So $1$ corrugation requires about $0.11\text{ m}$ of the width of the steel sheet. Find how many corrugations you can make with the steel sheet's total width of $2.2 \text{ m}$.

Finally, multiply the number of corrugations you have with the $7 \text{ cm}=0.07 \text{ m}$ diameter of each corrugation. Then you will find the width of the steel sheet after it is corrugated. Express your final answer in meters.

Comment: i.e. (2.2/0.11)*0.07 = 1.4 m of width

Comment: @diffracteD Please clarify what you mean. I'm not understanding.

Comment: just did as you said.

Comment: @diffracteD Ohh you're right! That is the correct solution. Sorry, I was not paying attention when writing my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

When corrugated,the length gets reduced by a factor $\dfrac{2 r}{\pi r}=\dfrac{2}{\pi} $.

Reduced length is 2.2 times above factor , calculating  to 1.4 m approximately.